# timeout errors when streaming a "text/html" string to S3 in Java

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I'm working in Java 11 on AWS 2.18.6

Ive got an inputstream made from a website that I'm trying to upload into S3 but I'm receiving a timeout error.

This error appears shortly after my bucket is created:

`requestId:85 DEBUG - Received failed response: 400`

Then this shows up further down

`ERROR - Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed.`

If I try to load a file it works without issue.

This is a sample of what I'm trying to do.

```java
URL url = new URL(http://www.example.org);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/html");
InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

PutObjectRequest request = PutObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucketName).key(s3Key).checksumAlgorithm(ChecksumAlgorithm.SHA256).checksumSHA256(checksum).contentLength((contentLength).contentType("text/html").build();
s3Client().putObject(request, RequestBody.fromInputStream(inputStream, contentLength));
inputStream.close();
```